# WinHTTP Decompression function?

Tags: http

Presently I am using winhttp api in c++ to get data from a server. The server can support various compression formats. So presently I want to use winhttp to get the compressed format (eg gzip) and decompress it. Is it possible to decompress the data using winhttp?

Comment: I had a similar issue. Instead of using WinHttp, it's easier to use WinINet. The porting is really quick and WinInet is of a higher level than WinHttp (it's actually a layer over it). Doing so makes @Sergey's answer's below applicable and efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Surely it's possible.

From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383955%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> To set the decoding option, the application calls InternetSetOption
>   with the handle returned from InternetOpen, InternetConnect, or
>   HttpOpenRequest. The INTERNET_OPTION_HTTP_DECODING option is specified
>   in the dwOption parameter, and the lpBuffer parameter points to a
>   boolean variable set to true. To disable decoding, the application
>   calls InternetSetOption with the INTERNET_OPTION_HTTP_DECODING option
>   and the boolean variable set to false.

So http compression is transprent for user code, you just need one call to `InternetSetOption` and your traffic will be compressed.

Comment: `InternetSetOption` is a WinINet function, not WinHTTP. WinHTTP does not support compression: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh227297(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Just use WinHttpSetOption() with WINHTTP_OPTION_DECOMPRESSION and WINHTTP_DECOMPRESSION_FLAG_GZIP, WINHTTP_DECOMPRESSION_FLAG_DEFLATE, or WINHTTP_DECOMPRESSION_FLAG_ALL. Supported in Windows 8.1 and newer.